# Strange conflict of XAML IsMouseOver and IsEnabled causing button to appear active when disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, opacity

In my application, I have a custom button style and template that has a couple states based on XAML triggers:

```
<Style x:Key="UniversalButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD7D7D7" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF999999" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF666666" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="ButtonBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                    </Style>

                    <Style x:Key="ButtonContent" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,7,8,8" />
                        <Setter Property="RecognizesAccessKey" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ContextMenu.IsOpen" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Border Style="{DynamicResource ButtonBorder}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ContentPresenter Style="{DynamicResource ButtonContent}"
                                          TextBlock.FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The specific instance of the button in question has a command with a `CanExecute` based on the selections of an `ItemsControl` in the view. When I toggle my selections, including those that are meant to disable the button, things work fine. The button becomes semi-transparent as I have called for in the XAML trigger for `IsEnabled`.

The problem starts when I mouse over the button, activating the storyboards above. After this happens, changing the selections to a state in which the button is disabled leaves the button fully opaque, regardless of the state of `IsEnabled`/`CanExecute`.

Through extensive debugging, I've determined that the issue is not caused by the `CanExecute` as previously thought, and that it must be linked to the `IsMouseOver` trigger. I've exhausted all of my XAML knowledge in trying to figure this conflict out and I'd be very grateful for help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is caused by [Dependency Property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF. In this case the animation (Timeline) has the default `FillBehavior` of `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`. After the animation finishes all the attempts to change the value (the `Opacity` property) should have a higher precedence. From the link you can see only system coercing the value can override the animation-based value (even locally setting such as by assignment directly in codebehind cannot override this).

That's why your template Trigger (whose precedence is 7) cannot override the current animated value. There are some solutions to this but I think you should use all storyboard in your triggers (instead of using a setter). If you don't want any animation, just set `Duration` to zero:

```
<Trigger Property="ContextMenu.IsOpen" Value="True">        
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                To=".8" Duration="0:0:0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <!-- similar for ExitActions --> 

</Trigger>

<!--  -->

<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                To=".6" Duration="0:0:0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <!-- similar for ExitActions --> 

</Trigger>
```

Using `Storyboard` this way is also good for maintenance. That's when you want to add some animation to the property value change, then you already have the Storyboard there and you can just add more options or animations...

**PS:** Don't be afraid of long XAML code. It's the nature and a characteristic of XAML code. However as a trade-off, we have more controls over the behaviors and effects.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks! Never had really researched this sort of precedence so I appreciate the knowledge. Further, I agree completely about writing long XAML... helps to adequately define the UI!

I've upgraded my trigger code to use `Storyboard`s instead of straight setters, and this fixed my issue with the disabled state, but now the `IsMouseOver` hover state isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Further, just determined that if I swap the trigger order, the `IsEnabled` problem comes back but the `IsMouseOver` problem is solved!

Comment: @TheTourer There is only one `IsMouseOver` trigger (in condition) in your code and I hope that's not what you meant. So what's the actual code for changing on `IsMouseOver`? If that's still based on normal trigger setter, you of course have to convert it to using Storyboard instead.

Comment: @TheTourer could you tell more about how the `IsMouseOver` (in your first comment) is not working? I don't really find any conflict here (I doubt your next problem is caused by some conflict between the Storyboards).

Comment: Thanks for the continued help King King! So I've done more testing with various scenarios and these are my findings: if I leave all three trigger sets in (`ContextMenu.IsOpen`, `IsEnabled`, `IsMouseOver`; in that order, and each with similar `EnterAction` and `ExitAction` `Storyboard`s), the problem in which hovering over the button breaks the `IsEnabled` `Opacity` state persists. If I remove the `IsMouseOver` `Trigger` case, the problem goes away and the `IsEnabled` `Opacity` change works all the time, even after hovering over the button. Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TheTourer I can produce your next issue now and it really surprised me. I could not believe that animation cannot override animation. Looks like the latter declared Storyboard (in XAML code) still has higher precedence (that's why swapping the code causes different issues). I now still don't understand this (of course have never encountered this before). I think you should try some work-around to solve this such as using some codebehind... sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm incredibly grateful for the help and you taught me something new about XAML (the styling precedence stuff). How can I best mark this answer to benefit you?

Comment: @TheTourer no, don't accept any answer if it does not solve your  problem (it's good for community). The reputation is not really important to me now (it was before :)

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem.

After several tests, I found the `ExitActions` of `IsEnabled` trigger, though finished its execution, would still somehow "stays" there and blocks the upcoming animation.

I haven't figured out the exact reason behind it, yet emprically, removing that storyboard before beginning another seems to solve the problem.

Codes like:

```
<Trigger Property="ContextMenu.IsOpen" Value="True">        
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="someStoryboard" />
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <!-- animation here -->

</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="someStoryboard">

</Trigger>
```